# ERROR: requested character too large for encoding

Tags: postgresql, encoding

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.6 on Linux.
I got an error when I do a test on [chr()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-string.html) function.

```
postgres=# select chr(1199111);
ERROR:  requested character too large for encoding: 1199111
postgres=# select chr(55296);
ERROR:  requested character not valid for encoding: 55296
postgres=# select chr(100000);
 chr
-----
 
(1 row)
```

Here, as you can see with value `100k` it worked (*didn't raise error*), however others didn't. I'm curious about that. Could someone please explain to me why ?

I attach test script

```
do
$$
declare 
str text ;
begin
for i in 1..1200000
loop
begin
select chr(i) into str;
exception when others then raise notice '=> i: %     => str: %', i , str ;
#exit; -- you can uncomment this star key
end ;
end loop;
end 
$$ ;
```

**UPDATED**

```
postgres=# show server_encoding;
 server_encoding
-----------------
 UTF8
(1 row)
```

Comment: Please add the result of `show server_encoding` to your question

Comment: @DanielVérité sorry for my late response, added `server_encoding`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it didn't raise an error, doesn't mean it *worked*. None of these *work*, but only one of them is so absurd as to make `chr()` explode.

- 100000 ([`186A0`](https://codepoints.net/U+I8A0)) maps to the Supplementary Multilingual Plane, but there is nothing there (yet).
- 55296 ([`U+D800`](https://codepoints.net/U+D800)) maps to the  Basic Multilingual Plane, but nothing is there (yet).
- 1199111 ([`U+124C07`](https://codepoints.net/U+124C07)) is not even valid, it maps to a plane so high that Unicode doesn't even support it.

Unicode only supports 1,111,998: 17 planes × 65,536 characters per plane - 2048 surrogates - 66 noncharacters. See [this answer for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5928054/124486). 1.11 Million code points, is far less than 1.19 Million code points.

Comment: Very good answer. Only one remark: while it is possible that in the future a character is assigned to 100000, which is in the Ideographic Script Area of the SMP, it is against the standard to assign a character to 55296, which is “permanently reserved” as a surrogate.

Comment: thanks,  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Supplementary_Multilingual_Plane